# Why is this sequence monotone increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across this problem showing the limit of this sequence $x_{n+1} = \log(2+x_{n}) , x_{0} = 0$ exists.
 This sequence is bounded above so I only need to show this sequence is monotone increasing. This is very intuitive, when you observe the graph of $y = \log(2+x)$ and $y=x$. But proving this formally is rather tricky to me. How can I prove that this sequence is monotone increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction !

Base case: $x_1=\log 2 >0=x_0.$

Now supoose that $(*) \quad x_{n+1}>x_n$ for some $n$.

Then

$$ x_{n+2}= \log (2+x_{n+1}) > \log(2+x_n)=x_{n+1}.$$

The $">"$ comes from $(*)$ and the fact, the $ \log$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it - just prove that the function $f(x)=\log(2+x)$ is increasing, either by looking at the graph, or by differentiation.